# Need advice in choosing right columns for clustered index in SQL Server 2012 (among list of given options)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012.

So here is the table

```
GroupCategoryType 
(
  GroupCategoryTypeID int identity(1,1) not null, --It is also a PK
  GroupTypeID int,
  id int,
  GroupCategoryID int,
  UserID int
)  
-- Total Rows around 60,000
```

I'm setting up a custom clustered index on this table as existing clustered index on GroupCategoryTypeID key is not much help (as no filtering/join is being done over this PK).

I have chosen `(GroupCategoryID, GroupTypeID, ID)` as these three are the most frequently used `in ('join','where')`
And the order I've mentioned here is as per their decreasing order of frequency of usage.

> Few points to note here about this (to be) clustered index are :
>
> 1. GroupTypeID can be either 1 or 2; it has least frequency of unique values i.e 2
>        GroupCategoryId has moderate frequency of unique values i.e 2200 # of unique values
>        ID has the highest frequency of unique values i.e 30,000
> 2. None of the possible combinations of pairs or triplet of these columns is unique.
>      Here are the few stats :
>
>    1. group by `GroupCategoryId,id` returns count(*) from 2 to 1600 for 700 rows out of total 55,000 and remaining 54,300 are unique.
>         To make it more clear, I used `select groupCategoryid,id,count(*) as total from GroupCategoryType group by groupCategoryid,id order by total desc`, and this returned 55000 rows.
>    2. group by `GroupCategoryId,GroupTypeID` returns count(*) ranging from 2 to 3200 for 700 rows out of total 2500 and remaining 1800 are unique.
>    3. group by `GroupTypeID,ID` returns count(*) ranging from 2 to 1600 for 6500 rows out of total 42000 and remaining 40,400 are unique.
>    4. group by `GroupCategoryid,grouptypeid,id` (triplet) returns count(*) ranging from 2 to 1600 for 700 rows out of total 52000 and remaining 51,300 are unique.

Now, my questions are :

1. What should be the best clustered index as per all these stats?  (Keeping in mind that GroupTypeid has just two unique values)
2. I know SQL Server will itself add a uniqueifier to make rows unique, but will it add this key to all the rows (even to those that are already unique) or just the duplicate ones ?
3. Considering Point #2 above, Should I add GroupCategoryTypeID to the clustered index to make all combinations unique?
4. If for example there is a query that uses just (col2,col3) or (col1,col3) or just (col3) in where clause, will the clustered index of (col1,col2,col3) still be used? 
   If not, is should creating a non-clustered index on (col2,col3) or (col1,col3) and separately for (col3) the best solution for such cases?

Comment: This is totally dependent on which version of SQL server you are using, 2016 has released a very efficient column store index - you need to review version specific indexes and when each should be used.

Comment: Why a clustered index?  Why not just a regular index?

Comment: @jimmy8ball : I've now mentioned SQL Server 2012 in my original question. Thanks.

Comment: Your table is narrow and 60k rows is small when it comes to databases. I'd keep the clustered index on the PK, leave it running for a week or so and check the Database Engine Tuning Advisor to see what index it recommends

Comment: What is main data access path to rows of this table `WHERE Col1 = @param1 AND ...` ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: These three columns are frequently getting used in where clause altogether `GroupCategoryID, GroupTypeID, ID`

Comment: Then I would create an UNIQUE clustered index on minimal set of these columns that unique identify ever row from this table.

Comment: But I've already mentioned in my Question that "None of the possible combinations of pairs or triplet of these columns is unique.".

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I've read that clustered indexes are much faster to read from. Also, 90% of the queries are using the columns in joins/where which I've mentioned. So I think changing current clustered index would help improving the performance of such reads. I'm learning in this field. I will appreciate if you put some light in this regard please.

Comment: @batman . . . It is better to learn about regular indexes first.  Clustered indexes have unexpected side effects on inserts and updates and can result in fragmented tables.  They are definitely useful -- don't get me wrong.  But I would not start with them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks Gordon, yeah I understand clustered indexes are not good when there are heavy reads/updates as it would cause to restructure records physically in data pages. In this table, the inserts/updates will be very rare, that's why I thought of setting up those keys as clustered which would boost the performance rather than simply keeping PK as the one. Do you still think I should consider setting up non-clustered considering this case ? Please suggest.

Comment: @batMan . . . Even infrequent inserts into the table will result in fragmentation over time.  I am inclined to have an identity column be the primary key and to let B-trees do the work for other indexing -- unless I have a good reason for choosing something else.

Answer (score 1):

What should be the best-clustered index as per all these stats? (Keeping in mind that GroupTypeid has just two unique values)

> **The best way to decide is analyzing the execution plan**, On the top of my head, my choice for these key is `(GroupTypeID, GroupCategoryID, ID)`. With this configuration, the head can read more linear avoid jumps just because are only two registers

I know SQL Server will itself add a uniqueifier to make rows unique, but will it add this key to all the rows (even to those that are already unique) or just the duplicate ones?

> The unique-identifiers inserted by SQL Server are used to control
>   transactions they are not to use as mundane primary-key.

Considering Point #2 above, Should I add GroupCategoryTypeID to the clustered index to make all combinations unique?

> Not necessarily, your clustered index must be the best for you use is not always the PK, in some cases, you can have a clustered index not unique. It is not usual but is possible.

If for ex. there is a query, that uses just (col2,col3) or (col1,col3) or just (col3) in where clause, will the clustered index of (col1,col2,col3) still be used ? If Not, then should creating a non-clustered index on (col2,col3) or (col1,col3) and separately for (col3), a best solution for such cases?

> Again, you need to check the execution plan, in some environments, a table with 60k register is too small and SQL Server, in others, this table is so big that you need a lot of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

A few times I've had success creating clustered indexes against the best practice of int/bigint and unique values. In one case I suggested creating a clustered index on a bigint column that was not even close to unique and it solved a big blocking problem we had.

The table in question, the most intensive queries would select millions of rows in some instances using that column as a filter. At first we had the clustered index on another bigint column that was unique in the table and it created a lot of locking issues.

I would look at your queries against this table and create the clustered index that gives the best performance and not necessarily in accordance with best practices on paper.